# Is there a difference when specifying upper bounds for wildcards explicitly?

Tags: java, generics, language-lawyer, wildcard, jls

Suppose I have a generic `class Generic<A extends BaseType>`.

Is there a notable difference, as far as the Java Language Specification is concerned, between the following two type declarations?

```
Generic<?>
Generic<? extends BaseType>
```

What about nested wildcards?

```
List<Generic<?>>
List<Generic<? extends BaseType>>
```

---

Thinking about this, I would assume these to be equivalent. `Generic` specifies that the type parameter `A`has `BaseType` for an upper bound.

Thus, the wildcard should always be "automatically" or "implicitly" bounded by `BaseType`, no matter whether I explicitly specify it or not.

Below, I try to reconcile my intution with the JLS.

---

I couldn't find information about "implicit" bounds, so I started by looking at subtyping rules.

Reading the JLS section about [subtyping $4.10.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2), it says:

> Given a generic type declaration `C<F1,...,Fn>` (n > 0), the direct supertypes of the parameterized type `C<T1,...,Tn>`, **where Ti (1 ≤ i ≤ n) is a type**, are all of the following:
>
> - `D<U1 θ,...,Uk θ>`, where `D<U1,...,Uk>` is a generic type which is a direct supertype of the generic type `C<T1,...,Tn>` and θ is the substitution [F1:=T1,...,Fn:=Tn].
> - `C<S1,...,Sn>`, where Si contains Ti (1 ≤ i ≤ n) (§4.5.1).

(emphasis mine)

From what I understand, "wildcards" are not considered "types" in the JLS. So this can't apply to the first two, but it would apply to the two `List` examples.

Instead, this should apply:

> Given a generic type declaration `C<F1,...,Fn>` (n > 0), the direct supertypes of the parameterized type `C<R1,...,Rn>` **where at least one of the Ri (1 ≤ i ≤ n) is a wildcard type argument**, are the direct supertypes of the parameterized type `C<X1,...,Xn>` which is the result of applying capture conversion to `C<R1,...,Rn>` ([§5.1.10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10)).

(emphasis mine)

Applying [capture conversion $5.1.10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10) to `Generic<?>` and `Generic<? extends BaseType>`; I think I get the same bounds on the fresh type variables. After capture conversion, I can use the "contains" rules to establish the subtyping.

For the first example, via

> If Ti is a wildcard type argument (§4.5.1) of the form ?, then Si is a fresh type variable whose upper bound is Ui[A1:=S1,...,An:=Sn] and whose lower bound is the null type (§4.1).

Since *A<sub>1</sub>* is `BaseType`, the fresh variable has an upper bound of `BaseType`.

For the second case, via

> If Ti is a wildcard type argument of the form ? extends Bi, then Si is a fresh type variable whose upper bound is glb(Bi, Ui[A1:=S1,...,An:=Sn]) and whose lower bound is the null type.
>
> glb(V1,...,Vm) is defined as V1 & ... & Vm.

I get `glb(BaseType, BaseType)`, which, again, is `BaseType`.

So it seems that the subtyping relationship between `Generic<?>` and `Generic<? extends BaseType>` goes both ways according to the JLS, which matches my intuition.

---

For the nested wildcards, I would use the ["contains" rule](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1-400):

> A type argument T1 is said to contain another type argument T2,
>   written T2 <= T1, if the set of types denoted by T2 is provably a
>   subset of the set of types denoted by T1 under the reflexive and
>   transitive closure of the following rules (where <: denotes subtyping
>   (§4.10)):
>
> - `? extends T <= ? extends S if T <: S`
> - `? extends T <= ?`
> - `? super T <= ? super S if S <: T`
> - `? super T <= ?`
> - `? super T <= ? extends Object`
> - `T <= T`
> - `T <= ? extends T`
> - `T <= ? super T`

Combined with

> `C<S1,...,Sn>, where Si contains Ti (1 ≤ i ≤ n) (§4.5.1).`

from above, I get:

`List<Generic<?>>` is a direct supertype of `List<Generic<? extends BaseType>>` if `Generic<?>` contains `Generic<? extends BaseType>>`

Although, I don't see how I use the contains rule. The only additional information I can use is subtyping, according to the rules. I already know that subtyping goes both ways between the two types.

Although, if contains with subtyping between the two were the answer, I could also show that `List<String>` is a subtype of `List<Object>` which it isn't and shouldn't be.

Further, I need to show something of the form `Type <= OtherType` and the only rule with a right-hand-side of the form "type" is `T <= T`, so these rules don't seem to help at all.

How do I get that `List<Generic<?>>` and `List<Generic<? extends BaseType>>` are subtypes of one another through the JLS?

Comment: Cannot explain the reason for this but you can add raw typed ```Generic``` values to ```List<Generic<?>>``` without complains but if you attempt to add it to a ```List<Generic<? extends Blah>>``` where ```Generic<T extends Blah>``` the compiler outputs a warning (javac 1.8.0_112).

Comment: It took me a while to realize that you actually have two questions here. The first one is basically self-answered already, after capture conversion, `List<Generic<?>>` becomes `List<Generic<#1 extends BaseType>>` and `List<Generic<? extends BaseType>>` becomes `List<Generic<#2 extends BaseType>>`, so the form doesn’t matter for most operations, but the other question is, which formal rule(s) allow to conclude that either is a subtype of the other, which would even be the same question when literally assigning `List<Generic<?>>` to `List<Generic<?>>`.

Comment: @Holger In a way, yes. The subtyping "question" is how I wanted to answer my "first"/original question. But maybe it can also be answered without subtyping and capture conversion etc. Did you mean to use my second example when writing this? From my interpretation of the JLS, capture conversion doesn't apply at all for these nested wildcards.

Comment: Great question. Took me some days. Even after searching that long, it’s hard to believe that there’s something missing in the specification, especially for a construct that doesn’t seem to be so obscure.

Answer (score 9):

Taking your initial question literally, whether “Is there a notable difference” between `Generic<?>` and `Generic<? extends BaseType>`, the answer must be, they are not equivalent.

[JLS §4.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1) clearly states:

> The wildcard `? extends Object` is equivalent to the unbounded wildcard `?`.

So it would be equivalent to `? extends BaseType` only if `BaseType` is `Object`, but even then, they are equivalent, but still bear notable differences, e.g. at places where no capture conversion happens:

```
boolean b1 = new Object() instanceof Supplier<?>; // valid code
boolean b2 = new Object() instanceof Supplier<? extends Object>; // invalid

Supplier<?>[] array1; // valid declaration
Supplier<? extends Object>[] array1; // invalid
```

It might be worth noting that contrary to the first intuition, given a declaration `Generic<T extends BaseType>`, specifying `Generic<? extends Object>` is as valid as the equivalent `Generic<?>`. The bounds to the wildcard are valid as long as they are not *provably distinct* to the type parameter’s bound and since the bounds are always subtypes of `Object`, `? extends Object` is always valid.

So if we have a type declaration like

```
interface NumberSupplier<N extends Number> extends Supplier<N> {}
```

we can write

```
NumberSupplier<? extends Object> s1;
NumberSupplier<? extends Serializable> s2;
NumberSupplier<? extends BigInteger> s3;
```

or even

```
NumberSupplier<? extends CharSequence> s4;
```

<sup>We can even implement it without an actual type extending `Number` and `CharSequence` using `() -> null`</sup>

but not

```
NumberSupplier<? extends String> s5;
```

as `String` and `Number` are *provably distinct*.

When it comes to assignments, we can use the subtyping rules already cited in the question to conclude that `NumberSupplier<? extends BigInteger>` is a subtype of `NumberSupplier<? extends Object>`, because `? extends BigInteger` *contains* `? extends Object` (and also *contains* `? extends Number`), because `BigInteger` is a subtype of `Object` and `Number`, but as you correctly noted, this does not apply to parameterized types whose type arguments are not wildcards.

So if we have declarations like `List<NumberSupplier<?>>`, `List<NumberSupplier<? extends Object>>`, or `List<NumberSupplier<? extends Number>>` and want to reason whether either is a subtype of the others according to §4.5.1’s *contains* rule, the only rule that could apply, is, when the type arguments are the *same* type (`T <= T`), but then, we wouldn’t need subtyping rules, as then, all these list types [are the same type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.4):

> Two reference types are the *same compile-time* type if they have the same binary name (§13.1) and their type arguments, if any, are the same, applying this definition recursively.

The *contains* rule still is useful, e.g. it allows to conclude that `Map<String,? extends Number>` is a subtype of `Map<String,Integer>`, because for the first type argument `String <= String` applies and the type arguments to the second type parameter are covered by a wildcard specific *contains* rule.

---

So the remaining question is, which rule allows us to conclude that `NumberSupplier<?>`, `NumberSupplier<? extends Object>`, or `NumberSupplier<? extends Number>` are the same types, so that `List<NumberSupplier<?>>`, `List<NumberSupplier<? extends Object>>`, or `List<NumberSupplier<? extends Number>>` are assignable to each other.

It doesn’t seem to be *capture conversion*, as *capture conversion* would imply calculating effective bounds, but also create a “fresh type variable” for each wildcard that is definitely a different type. But there is no other rule covering wildcard compatibility. Or I didn’t find it. Trying to match the specification with the actual behavior of `javac` had some very interesting results:

Given

```
interface MySupplier<S extends CharSequence&Appendable> extends Supplier<S> {}
```

The following declarations are obviously valid:

```
List<MySupplier<? extends CharSequence>> list1 = Collections.emptyList();
List<MySupplier<? extends Appendable>>   list2 = Collections.emptyList();
```

Since in both cases, the wildcard’s bound is redundant as matching one of `S`’s bound, we might guess that they are actually the same type.

But `javac` thinks they are not

```
list1 = list2; // compiler error
list2 = list1; // dito
```

though any operation involving *capture conversion* does conclude compatible types, e.g.

```
list1.set(0, list2.get(0)); // no problem
list2.set(0, list1.get(0)); // no problem
```

and doing the rejected assignments indirectly works:

```
List<MySupplier<?>> list3;
list3 = list1;
list2 = list3; // no problem
// or
list3 = list2;
list1 = list3; // again no problem
```

but here, `?` is not equivalent to `? extends Object`:

```
List<MySupplier<? extends Object>> list4;
list4 = list1; // compiler error
list2 = list4; // dito
// or
list4 = list2; // dito
list1 = list4; // dito
```

but again, indirect assignments work.

```
list4 = list3 = list1; // works
list1 = list3 = list4; // works
list4 = list3 = list2; // works
list2 = list3 = list4; // works
```

So whatever rule `javac` uses here, it’s not transitive, which rules out subtype relationships, as well as a general “it’s the same type” rule. It seems, that this is truly un(der)specified, and directly affects the implementation. And, as currently implemented, `?` without bounds is special, allowing an assignment chain that is not possible with any other wildcard type.

Comment: As of why list1 = list2 gives compilation error.

According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1

Two type arguments are provably distinct if one of the following is true:

Each type argument is a type variable or wildcard, with upper bounds (from capture conversion, if necessary) of S and T; and neither |S| <: |T| nor |T| <: |S|.

And: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6

The erasure of a type variable (§4.4) is the erasure of its leftmost bound.

Comment: @Klaimmore but there is no clear statement about whether and when the “provably distinct” rule should apply in assignments. You know, you *can* assign a `MySupplier<? extends CharSequence>` to a `MySupplier<? extends Appendable>` and vice versa, which doesn’t contradict your cited rules, as it refers to the bounds “from capture conversion, if necessary”. There is no indicator that the “provably distinct” rule has been used by the compiler for the list assignments, especially, as it wouldn’t explain why `List<MySupplier<? extends Object>>` is not assignable.

Comment: *"boolean b2 = new Object() instanceof Supplier<? extends Object>;"* ... my understanding that this statement fails irrespective of any nuanced subtype analysis simply because the `instanceof` operator requires a *reifiable type*, and the only wildcard type that is reifiable is `<?>` (the semantic equivalence is granted).

Comment: @scottb is this a contradiction? The specification says “`? extends Object` is equivalent to the unbounded wildcard `?`”, but it is not. That’s the whole point. If it was truly and fully equivalent, `Supplier<? extends Object>` was treated as a reifiable type.