# Which part of the JLS specifies that you can't cast from List<? extends List<Superclass>> to List<List<Subclass>>?

Tags: java, language-lawyer

(This question is inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66037939/5133585), which I incorrectly answered.)

This code does not compile:

```
List<? extends List<Number>> list = new ArrayList<>();
List<List<Double>> anotherList = (List<List<Double>>) list;
```

Note that IntelliJ doesn't report any errors. It only fails to compile when I click "Run".

I understand why this doesn't compile on a conceptual level. `list` is a list of "something that extends `List<Number>`", and that "something" can never be `List<Double>`, because `List<Double>` is not a subtype of `List<Number>`, and because no type can implement both since they have the same erasure.

However, when I tried to follow the wording in the language specification to determine whether this cast is valid, I found that the language spec seems to say that this is a valid cast!

Here is my reasoning:

The cast fulfils all three requirements for there to be a Narrowing Reference Conversion from `S` (`List<? extends List<Number>>`) to `T` (`List<List<Double>>`).

> **[5.1.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.6.1). Allowed Narrowing Reference Conversion**
>
> A narrowing reference conversion exists from reference type S to
> reference type T if all of the following are true:
>
> - S is not a subtype of T
> - If there exists a parameterized type X that is a supertype of T, and a parameterized type Y that is a supertype of S, such that the
>   erasures of X and Y are the same, then X and Y are not provably
>   distinct (§4.5).
> - One of the following cases applies:
>
>   - S and T are interface types.
>   - [...]

The first and third points are trivially true. To show that the second point is true, we take `Collection<List<Double>>` to be a parameterised super type of `List<List<Double>>`, and `Collection<? extends List<Number>>` to be a parameterised super type of `List<? extends List<Number>>`. They both erase to the same type `Collection`. Now we need to show that `Collection<? extends List<Number>>` and `Collection<List<Double>>` are not [provably distinct (§4.5)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5). The same argument also works for `Iterable<...>`.

<sub>Edit: I just realised that the supertypes of `List<List<Double>>` also include things like `List<? extends List<Double>>`, not just the superinterfaces of `List`. But I don't think that will invalidate this argument, as the point is that 1. out of `X` and `Y` there is at least one wildcard 2. the wildcard bounds/type arguments of `X` and `Y` are subtypes of each other.</sub>

> Two parameterized types are provably distinct if either of the
> following is true:
>
> - They are parameterizations of distinct generic type declarations.
> - Any of their type arguments are provably distinct.

Clearly, since they both erase to the same type, the first condition can't be true. We only need to show that the second condition is false.

In [§4.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1), the spec defines "type arguments are provably distinct":

> Two type arguments are provably distinct if one of the following is
> true:
>
> - [...]
> - One type argument is a type variable or wildcard, with an upper bound (from capture conversion (§5.1.10), if necessary) of S; and the
>   other type argument T is not a type variable or wildcard; and neither
>   |S| <: |T| nor |T| <: |S| (§4.8, §4.10).

(The other (trivially false) conditions are not shown for brevity) Here, `S` is `List<Number>` and `T` is `List<Double>`. Both |S| <: |T| and |T| <: |S| holds, as |S| and |T| are the same type. Yes, the subtype relation is reflexive, because the super type relation is reflexive (it's defined as the reflexive and transitive closure on the *direct* supertype relation).

Therefore the type arguments of `Collection<? extends List<Number>>` and `Collection<List<Double>>` are not provably distinct, and so `List<? extends List<Number>>` and `List<List<Double>>` are not provably distinct, and so there is (or *should be*) a conversion from `List<? extends List<Number>>` to `List<List<Double>>`!

Where is the error in my reasoning? Is there some other part of the spec that I missed?

Comment: `List<? extends List<Number>>` means, it could be a `List<ArrayList<Number>>` or a `List<LinkedList<Number>>`. But not a `List<List<Double>>`.

Comment: I [hate](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8033709) narrowing capture conversion with regards to bounded wildcards. This is probably the 4-th time in my lifetime that I hit similar problems. Specifically, what in the world is _from capture conversion (§5.1.10), **if necessary**_. What do you mean _if necessary_. Isn't capture conversion _ALWAYS_ applied? And of course "upper bound ..." of that. `JLS` does not explain (at least to me), what that is. I really want to know an answer too :(

Comment: Or even read this [issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8078084) that says : "Otherwise, map wildcards and type variables to their upper bounds, and then test whether their erasures are related classes or interfaces (that is, one erased type is a subtype of the other)", only immediately after to say : _This is unsound..._. To me this is a `JLS` bug(s), but I am too afraid to post as an answer.

Comment: @Eugene reminds me on the second half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48347198/2711488) which is about assignments (without casts), but still a similar (or even the same) unsoundness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'll just say it after [Holger's confirmation and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48347198/2711488): JLS is underspecified (at least) at this location. There are some related JDK bugs that work around the same idea, noticeable [this one](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8078084), that directly hits your question via:

> .... Otherwise, map wildcards and type variables to their upper bounds, and then test whether their erasures are related classes or interfaces (that is, one erased type is a subtype of the other)

Only to immediately start the next sentence with:

> This is unsound...

So, that bug admits that JLS needs some corrections around this chapter(s).

What I have been struggling with too from your quotes of the JLS are two points:

- One type argument is a type variable or wildcard, with an upper bound **(from capture conversion (§5.1.10), if necessary)**...

  I do know what *capture conversion* is, but I was not aware it might be optional to be performed (via that "if necessary"). I always thought that it is performed at each location, all the time.
- What is an *upper bound* from a *captured conversion type*?

  In your case, is that *upper bound* `List<Number>` or `List<?>`, for example? In my understanding (or lack of precise JLS explanation), this could be understood either way.

All these (+ your great scrape of the JLS) makes me wonder about the correctness of the JLS here, especially since `javac` is not following these exact same rules.

Comment: Capture conversion does not happen with `instanceof`, as well as for the left hand side of assignments (otherwise, you couldn’t do `List<?> list = expression;`).

Comment: @Holger slightly confused me here. Is this comment for a different Q&A? Or, if here, can I get a bit of details of what you mean please?

Comment: A response to “I always thought that it is performed at each location, all the time.”